# don't display .php extension in address bar(php)

Tags: url, url-rewriting

First of all this method clearly working on github, for example pages showing done:

```
https://github.com/account
https://github.com/inbox
```

There is no .php extension at all + not needed **?page=account** or **?page=inbox**

In my opinion it's done via .htaccess.

Maybe someone knows how it should look in order to archieve same effect like github site ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved using mod_rewrite for apache

You put a .htaccess file in your document root and give it rules (Regular Expressions) to match the called URLs with

It looks similar to this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# rule to call MyPage.php if you call the URL http://yourdomain.com/MyPage
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# rule to add GET params
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

There are several tutorials regarding mod_rewrite on the internet